# MySQL - Why is this slow running query not using (what seems to be) the correct index?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

This query works, and does what I want it to do, but is awfully slow running.  We have a table of transactions that holds an amount, a user ID, a partner ID, and a description. When a user has 3 of a specific transaction they get a one-time bonus.

```
SELECT t.str_spid, count(*) AS C
  FROM transactions t
  LEFT JOIN transactions AS x
    ON t.str_spid = x.str_spid
   AND x.str_prid = 148
   AND x.str_amount = 2500
 WHERE t.str_prid = 148
   AND (t.str_desc = "Annual Rewards" OR t.str_desc = "Annual Rewards (PRO)")
   AND t.str_amount = 2000
   AND x.str_spid IS NULL
 GROUP BY t.STR_SPID 
HAVING C = 3
 LIMIT 0,100;
```

I have an indexes on the individual fields, and then composite indexes as follows:

```
SPID_DE_PRID: STR_SPID, STR_DESC, STR_PRID
SPID_DE_PRID_AMT: STR_SPID, STR_AMOUNT, STR_DESC, STR_PRID
```

When I use explain I get possible keys (on t):

```
STR_SPID,STR_PRID,STRAMT,STRDESC,SPID_PRID,SPID_DE_PRID,SPID_DE_PRID_AMT
```

And key used:  STR_PRID

On x I get possible:

```
STR_SPID,SPT_SOID,STRAMT,SPID_PRID,SPID_DE_PRID,SPID_DE_PRID_AMT
```

And key used: STR_SPID

Is there a better index or way to rewrite this so that it runs any faster?

Comment: Are you sure that's your query? You join on `t.str_spid=x.str_spid` but also have a condition that `x.str_spid IS NULL`. No rows of `x` can ever satisfy this join, so you might as well eliminate the join to `x` from the query completely.

Comment: Editing now - wow - I missed an entire section of it!

Comment: Editing now - wow - I missed a where clause that excludes the user if they already have the bonus

Answer (score 1):

You search `t` for specific values in `str_prid` and `str_desc`, so those should be the first two columns of an index, but you don't have such an index.

The optimizer does its best with the single-column index on `str_prid`, to narrow down the search.

If you had an index on `(str_prid, str_amount, str_desc, str_spid)` that's what I would expect would have the best optimization for `t`.

Then for `x`, you'd want to look up matching rows, so you'd want and index on `(str_spid, str_prid, str_amount)`.